# Login/Register with fetch in API doesn't work and gives an error that a property was not defined

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

I have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login-page.css">
  <script defer src="login-page.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main-holder">
    <h1 id="login-header">Login</h1>
    
    <div id="login-error-msg-holder">
      <p id="login-error-msg">Invalid username <span id="error-msg-second-line">and/or password</span></p>
    </div>
    
    <form id="login-form">
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login-form-submit">
    </form>
  
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

and this js:

```
const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-form-submit");
const loginErrorMsg = document.getElementById("login-error-msg");

loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const username_ = loginForm.username.value;
    const password_ = loginForm.password.value;

fetch('https://www.fulek.com/data/api/user/register', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "username": loginForm.username.value,
    "password": loginForm.password.value
  })
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
    if (username === "user" && password === "web_dev") {
        alert("You have successfully logged in.");
        location.reload();
    } else {
        loginErrorMsg.style.opacity = 1;
    }
})
```

but I got this error
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

and that's the API's response:

```
URL (POST): https://www.fulek.com/data/api/user/register
BODY (JSON):
{
    "username":"some.email.52384@racunarstvo.hr",
    "password":"xxyyzz"
}
```

I have tried a few things but since I don't have much experience with frontend, I can't really resolve the issue.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/moUus.png

Comment: Typo?  You define a variable called `username_` and try to reference a variable called `username`.

Comment: @David it was  `"username": username_, "password": password_` but it still didn't work, can you point me out the mistake as I don't understand what's wrong. username is because that's how I refer to it in the API, right?

Comment: Well, which specific line of code does the error refer to?  For the `username` variable used on that specific line of code, where is it defined?

Comment: Well it was a stupid mistake in the if statement where you were right, I use username instead of username_, thank you for opening my eyes :)